# Wordpress get Custom post title

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress programming
I created a WordPress postal warehouse called "wp_locations"
I need to show the title of this post on the page
I put the following code in the my theme index file

```
<?php $gallery_args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'orderby'=> 'date',
            'order'=> 'DESC',
            'post_type'=> 'wp_locations',
            'post_status'=> 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true 
    );
$posts_display_gallery = get_posts( $gallery_args ); 
foreach($posts_display_gallery as $rows){
    $post_title = $rows->post_title;
} ?>
```

But did not display the title
please guide me

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Comment: Have you tried to `echo $post_title`?

Comment: Missing 'echo'  from your code

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and check it again....

```
 <?php

    global $post;
   $gallery_args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'orderby'=> 'date',
            'order'=> 'DESC',
            'post_type'=> 'wp_locations',
            'post_status'=> 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true 
    );
   $posts_display_gallery = get_posts( $gallery_args ); 
    foreach ( $posts_display_gallery as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
     $post_title = $post->post_title; // Like this you will get post title.
     echo $post_title;  // For display
 endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Please update your answer to explain what this does and how it fixes the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank for comment @FluffyKitten. I have updated the answer as your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everybody
I forgot the echoو My problem has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Please use echo in your code

```
echo $post_title = $rows->post_title;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $gallery_args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'orderby'=> 'date',
            'order'=> 'DESC',
            'post_type'=> 'wp_locations',
            'post_status'=> 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true 
    );
$posts_display_gallery = get_posts( $gallery_args ); 
foreach($posts_display_gallery as $rows){
    $post_title = $rows->post_title;

    echo $post_title; // for display the title
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this piece of code, should work

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $loop->have_posts() ){
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        $product_id = $loop->post->ID;
        $product_title = $loop->post->post_title;
    endwhile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try get_the_title() in the foreach loop